# How to make numpy function faster with numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have heard about numba , that it makes the execution time faster.
I have tried it like this way

```
@jit
def abs_diffs_signal(data):
    return np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(data,axis=0)),axis=0)
```

Its giving me following warning
`Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "abs_diffs_signal" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject`
And it is making the process slow.

SO what should I do to make it faster.

I am calling above function like this way

```
subjects_data.agg([ 'min',abs_diffs_signal])
```

where as subjects_data is a groupby function

Comment: Numba isn't going to help you if your code is already written as vectorized operation. You could write a loop that does the same thing, which numba could compile to work faster, potentially.

Comment: What is the shape of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to outperform already vectorized numpy functions, it is always a good idea to simplify the code a bit (except BLAS-calls on larger arrays).
All numpy functions on their own are quite fast, but numpy allocates temporary arrays in this example, which is quite costly and also leads to cache misses if you increase the array size.

**Example 2D-Input**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def abs_diffs_signal_np(data):
    return np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(data,axis=0)),axis=0)

@nb.njit()
def abs_diffs_signal(data):
    res=np.zeros(data.shape[1],dtype=data.dtype)
    for i in range(data.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            res[j]+=np.abs(data[i+1,j]-data[i,j])
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
data=np.random.rand(1_000_000,20)
np.allclose(abs_diffs_signal_np(data),abs_diffs_signal(data))
#True
%timeit abs_diffs_signal_np(data)
#402 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit abs_diffs_signal(data)
#12.2 ms ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: With current numba (0.58.1) and numpy (1.24.4), I am getting `64.1 ms ± 645 µs per loop` and `9.88 ms ± 183 µs per loop` respectively for each of the two implementations, so the loop unrolloing and numba yield approx. a 6:1 ratio difference, not the approximate 40:1 ratio from the original post, but still makes the point.

Answer (score 0):

The full error message:

```
In [155]: abs_diffs_signal(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
<ipython-input-154-3b4e0175a309>:1: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "abs_diffs_signal" failed type inference due to: No implementation of function Function(<function diff at 0x7fcf048dc488>) found for signature:
 
 >>> diff(array(int64, 2d, C), axis=Literal[int](0))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'np_diff_impl': File: numba/np/arraymath.py: Line 3374.
    With argument(s): '(array(int64, 2d, C), axis=Literal[int](0))':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypeError: np_diff_impl() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py:675

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function diff at 0x7fcf048dc488>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-154-3b4e0175a309> (3)


File "<ipython-input-154-3b4e0175a309>", line 3:
def abs_diffs_signal(data):
    return np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(data,axis=0)),axis=0)
    ^

  @numba.jit
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:178: NumbaWarning: Function "abs_diffs_signal" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "<ipython-input-154-3b4e0175a309>", line 2:
@numba.jit
def abs_diffs_signal(data):
^

  state.func_ir.loc))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:188: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-154-3b4e0175a309>", line 2:
@numba.jit
def abs_diffs_signal(data):
^

  state.func_ir.loc))
Out[155]: array([8, 8, 8, 8])
```

I'm not an expert on `numba`, but it appears that its implementation of `np.diff` does not work with an `axis` parameter.  Is that documented?

According to `numba` docs

> numpy.diff() (only the 2 first arguments)

> def diff(a, n=1, axis=-1, prepend=np._NoValue, append=np._NoValue):

So `a` and `n` are supported but not `axis`.  `diff` is a rather simple.  For 1d it is just `arr[1:]-arr[:-1]`.  So you should be able to replace it with an expansion.

In general you can't just throw a `jit` around a `numpy` function and expect it work, let alone work faster.  Sometimes it does, but there are plenty of case where you need to pay attention both to the error messages, and the documentation.  It's not a no-brainer tool!